# Proof P by premises $(\neg P\vee Q)\to P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to proof next question by a formal proof that when the premise is equal to:
$(\neg P\vee Q)\to P$ has the result ,$P$, I first though that I must write:

$\neg P\vee Q\to P$, as:
$\neg(\neg P\vee Q)\vee P$ and work further from there.

The problem is that I only may use Reit ,introduction and Elimination. Can someone help me?

Comment: Start by assuming $\neg P$, derive a contradiction and use $\neg$ Elim.

Comment: Are you allowed to draw a truth table? That would be the most straightforward method.

Comment: I am not allowed to draw a truth table. I must write a formal proof like when you write it in latex as \fitch{}{}.

Comment: I know that i must start with the assumption$\neg P$\, because we start with\,$(\neg P\vee Q)$\, but i do not understand how i must go further

Comment: Maybe you can review [Fitch rules](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~brianwc/courses/logic/rulesummary.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all ,you should know that implication connector does not have disribution property on right hand side.

$(\neg P \lor Q)\rightarrow P$ is equal to $(\neg P \rightarrow P)\land (Q\rightarrow P)$

$(\neg P \rightarrow P)\land (Q\rightarrow P)$ $\equiv$ $( P \lor P)\land (\neg Q\lor P)$

So, $P \land (\neg Q\lor P)$ , by elimination

$\therefore P$

Comment: Could you explain maybe the second line?

Comment: @LenieGoossens , I used De-morgan's law to turn implication into disjuction on both sides

Comment: @LenieGoossens https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:~:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,both%20valid%20rules%20of%20inference.&text=The%20rules%20allow%20the%20expression,of%20each%20other%20via%20negation.

Comment: I learnt De-morgan's law today, so i do not think we have to use that. besides that, we have learnt that with De-morgan law we can turn:

Comment: a discjunction in a conjunction and visa vesa but that is it

Comment: @LenieGoossens do you know modus ponens?

Comment: Never heard of that

Comment: @LenieGoossens are you high school pupil or university?

Comment: University, first years, second period

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** using Boolean algebra,

$$\overline{\left( \overline{p} + q \right)} + p = p \overline{q} + p = p \,(\overline{q} + 1) = p$$

Answer (score 0):

> I have to proof next question by a formal proof that when the premise is equal to:
> $(\neg P\vee Q)\to P$ has the result ,$P$, I first though that I must write:
>
> $\neg P\vee Q\to P$, as:
> $\neg(\neg P\vee Q)\vee P$ and work further from there.
>
> The problem is that I only may use Reit ,introduction and Elimination. Can someone help me?

Indeed, that is not a fundamental inference in Natural Deduction.  Well, sure, you may derive it, but it is not really that efficient a strategy in the system.

To derive a consequent from its conditional, you would either (1) derive the antecedent so to use conditional elimination, or (2) show that a contradition would be derived under an assumption of the negation of that consequent, so to use *reduction to absurdity*.  Strategy (1) cannot be done here, thus you should attempt strategy (2).

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~(\lnot p\lor q)\to p\hspace{2ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~2.~\lnot p\hspace{9ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{~~3.~\\~~4.~\\~~5.~\bot\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Negation Elimination (?,?)}}\\~~6.~\lnot\lnot p\hspace{11ex}\textsf{Negation Introduction (2-5)}\\~~7.~p\hspace{14ex}\textsf{Double Negation Elimination (6)}}$$

So, determine what you will be contradicting, and a way you would derive that.

Answer (score 0):

- Suuppose ( for refutation) that  P is false.
- It means that the true premise  $(\neg P \lor Q) \rightarrow P$ has a false consequent.
- The only way for a true conditional with a false consequent to be true is to have a false antecedent ( by the truth table of the " if ... then " operator). So $(\neg P \lor Q)$ has to be false.
- By DeMorgan's , the negation of a disjunction amounts to a conjoint negation of its disjuncts. So $\neg ( \neg P \lor Q) \equiv ( \neg \neg   P \& ~Q )$
- Appliy $\&$ Elim to get $\neg \neg   P$
- The hypothesis $\neg P$ led you to the negation of this hypothesis, namely $\neg \neg   P$.
- By Neg Intro Rule, you're entitled to conclude that the hypothesis was false, wich means that $\neg \neg   P$ is true, and ( by Double Negation ) that P is true.